# Filtering AWS describeInstances request parameters

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I am using the node.js code below to list my AWS instances. However, it returns a lot of data that I am not interested in. I would like to retrieve only the dns-name and ip-address. I can certainly filter them afterwards, but is it possible to limit the retrieval to only those 2 fields?

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = function (event, context) {
    console.log("\n\nLoading handler\n\n");
    var ec2 = new AWS.EC2();
    ec2.describeInstances(function (err, data) {
        console.log("\nIn describe instances:\n");
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else console.log("\n\n" + JSON.stringify(data) + "\n\n"); // successful response

        context.done(null, 'Function Finished!');
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't send a custom request to EC2 that will cause it to return only the attributes that you are interested in (the IP address and public DNS).

You would have to filter the undesirable attributes out of the results, perhaps using object destructuring, or map(), or lodash. Maybe something like this:

```
const _ = require('lodash');

const rc = _.flatten(data.Reservations.map((r) => {
    return r.Instances.map((i) => {
      return _.pick(i, ['PublicDnsName', 'PublicIpAddress']);
    });
}));
```

That would yield something like:

```
[
    {"PublicDnsName":"ec2-52-1-1-1.compute-1.amazonaws.com","PublicIpAddress":"52.1.1.1"},
    {"PublicDnsName":"ec2-52-2-2-2.compute-1.amazonaws.com","PublicIpAddress":"52.2.2.2"},
    {"PublicDnsName":"ec2-52-3-3-3.compute-1.amazonaws.com","PublicIpAddress":"52.3.3.3"},
]
```